# Why do I have to run pip install <package name> sometimes and other times no?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

Sometimes I have to run pip install  on terminal so I can load the library on Jupiter Notebook. But sometimes I don't have to do anything besides running import

Why is that?

Comment: Not all libraries are installed by default, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) comes with many packages ([Anaconda package lists](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs/)), which you can already import.  If the distribution doesn't contain a package, you should first try to install it with [`conda install <package>`](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/).  If the package is not part of conda, then you [`pip install <package>`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages).